# They are coming

Tags: riddle

I've just found this solemn poem, entitled "They are coming." Unfortunately, the name of the author has been lost. However, I am confident that the poem contains enough information to identify the author. Can you help?

---

> **They are coming.**
>   <sub>(author unknown)</sub>
>
> I am so powerful, but I am frail.
>   My allies surround me, but my enemies grow near.
>   I am afraid that soon, all will fail.
>   My troops are thinning. There is much fear.
>
> They are coming.
>
> The world is mine... but I can hardly walk.
>   I look up and see nothing but my foe's baleful stare.
>   The priests are dead. I can almost hear them talk.
>   A sound startles me, but it is only the whinny of a mare.
>
> They are coming.
>
> The clock is ticking. Time is running out.
>   The enemy is organizing. We are surrounded. I must fight.
>   The clunk of wood and shattering of stone rings like a shout.
>   The endless battle. The never-ending war of dark against light.
>
> They are coming.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is this about

> A chess game?

Clues:

> I am so powerful, but I am frail.

My allies surround me, but my enemies grow near.

> Describe the King, which is the most powerful piece but can only travel one square at a time. At the beginning of the game he is surrounded by pieces of the same color

The priests are dead. I can almost hear them talk.

A sound startles me, but it is only the whinny of a mare.

> The bishop and the knight

The clock is ticking. Time is running out.

> Refers to a timed chess game

The enemy is organizing. We are surrounded. I must fight.

> Probably refers to the endgame or a [mating pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checkmate_pattern) that requires the king to move

The clunk of wood

> Chess pieces are often made of wood

shattering of stone

> Refers to the Rook

The never-ending war of dark against light.

> Black pieces and white pieces

Comment: This is correct!